# Format XML code in Eclipse

Tags: xml, eclipse, formatting

When I write .xml files in Eclipse, I often have to manually indent code. For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/background"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

After formatting it looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout   
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:background="@color/background"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

How to automate this? I can't find formatting settings in Eclipse for XML.

Comment: `CTRL + A` to select the entire text and then `CTRL + SHIFT + F`

Comment: I know of this feature. Where do I set it up? I can't find it in Window->Preferences->XML. I don't like the way it cuts attributes.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Will do it for you, and you can configure it in

```
Window -> Preferences -> XML -> Xml Files -> Editor
```

Comment: I know of this feature. Where do I set it up? I can't find it in Window->Preferences->XML. I don't like the way it cuts attributes.

Comment: if options in  Window->Preferences->XML->Xml Files->Editor not enough then I don't know the answer

Comment: Took me awhile to figure out there are actually two "sub-tabs" in the Eclipse XML Editor, "Design" and "Source", and this only applies to the "Source" one. The "sub-tabs" are underneath the actual editor tab/view.

Comment: This does not solve the issue for me, There is no "Save Action" menu as there is for Java. If I have a document that already has Tabs and spaces in. When I click save, the tabs are not removed and converted to spaces.

Comment: and then "[v] Split multiple attributes each on a new line" and then ReStart eclipse.

Answer (score 38):

As stated above, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will auto-format. However, by default Eclipse will split attributes in a naive way. If you're like me and prefer to have all the attributes on their own lines, go to Window→Preferences→XML→XML Files→Editor and check *Split multiple attributes each on a new line*.

Answer (score 15):

You need to open the file using the XML Editor, swap to Source view and then do the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> trick.

Comment: It's critical to open the XML file using the XML Editor in order for CTRL+Shift+F key combination to work.

Answer (score 14):

CMD + SHIFT + F for Macintosh users

Comment: this doesn't work for me under OSX Mavericks, using the Eclipse Luna Modeling Tools configuration.

Comment: This is the correct _default_ key sequence for autoformat. It's possible to change it, or to have a plugin change/interfere with it. Which can be annoying!

Answer (score 3):

open windows->preferences->xml files->editor
enter some high number for **line width**, say 999 and then format the xml file with ctrl+shift+F.

You ll see the lines are aligned properly.

Comment: this answer is already posted. then why are posting it again the same answer...??

Answer (score -2):

You can set the default XML editor to “Java Editor”:

- Right-click on the XML
- Open With
- Other...
- Java Editor

This applies all java formatting and controls over XML file.