# custom xml formatting eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I want eclipse to format my xml into columns like the code below.  Is there any possible way to do this in eclipse?  I have tried Preferences->XML->Editor and changed some settings but I couldn't get the format I exactly wanted. If anyone knows of these settings could you please tell me?

```
     <ListView
        style                               =   "@style/listview"
        android:layout_below                =   "@+id/plu_enter_layout"
        android:layout_above                =   "@+id/fpc_scan_again"
        android:fadeScrollbars              =   "false" 
    />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width                =   "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height               =   "wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop       =   "true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal     =   "true"
        android:layout_marginTop            =   "20dp"
        android:orientation                 =   "horizontal" 
    >
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format XML code in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527474/format-xml-code-in-eclipse)

Comment: I have tried this and couldn't get my code to split into columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this plugin: http://editorxml.sourceforge.net/contentAssit.html

It seems the Template section is what you are looking for.

I hope it helps.