# JSF Code formatter or Eclipse XML Editor, each tag for new line?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, code-formatting

How to format `JSF` code in eclipse?

I already try as the following :

- [Format XML code in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527474/format-xml-code-in-eclipse)

My `XML Editor` Configuration Setting is  :

- Line width **120**
- Split multiple attributes each on a new like **Checked**
- Align final bracket in mulit-line element tags  **Checked**
- Clear all blank lines **Checked**

If I do `Ctrl + Shif + F`, eclipse format the code as below.

```
<tr>
    <td><h:outputText value="#{label['MANAGE_USER_TITLE']}"
            styleClass="table-title" /></td>

</tr>
```

My expectation format is, after `Ctrl + Shif + F`

```
<tr>        
    <td>
        <h:outputText value="#{label['MANAGE_USER_TITLE']}" styleClass="table-title" /> 
                ▲
                This line may be wrap base on line size.
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can I do for that? Is there any plugin? 
I already try `HTML Tidy`, I can only format `HTML`, not `JSF` code.

**Update**

Picture -1

[image]

Eclipse Setting for Picture-1

[image]

Picture - 2 (I want)

[image]

Comment: remove `<tr>` and `<td>` tags from the Inline Elements list.

Comment: @Kuba thanks, it is my expectation. Could you post as answer with picture or more explanation to make good reference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the Settings panel that Maheshbabu Jammula posted, you can see an Inline Elements list. Just remove `<tr>` and `<td>` tags from the list and those tags will always land in a new line. Take Care!

Preferences > Web > HTML Files > Editor

[image]

Comment: Yes @Kuba
Open Window>Preferences>Web>HMTL Files>Editor and you will find list of HTML keywords in textbox called “Inline Elements:”. Remove input and label from this list and all of these statements will be each on separate lines.

You can modify more formatter settings there. Line wrapping width is reasonable to be increased with nowadays widescreen monitors.

Comment: @Maheshbabu Jammula - not everyone uses Windows, on a Mac there's no Window>Preferences

Answer (score 6):

```
Ctrl + Shif + F, only formats code.For indent use ctrl+a and ctrl+i
```

[image]

Comment: Did u test it my code? It is the same format I don't want.

Comment: @cycDemo stay same: Split multiple attributes each on a new like Checked

Comment: Please check my update post. I did not get my expectation(Picture-2) format.

Comment: Split multiple attributes each on a new like Checked

Comment: I am sorry, may be my false. Even it is checked or not, it is the same. I already test most the editor and formatter option.

Comment: Thank for your supporting! I get useful reference your answer.