# Eclipse: format JSF/XHTML/HTML/... files with each attribute on same line, but column-wise

Tags: html, eclipse, xhtml, code-formatting

In Eclipse, I find no way to format code the way I need to for JSF, XHTML, HTML or XML files like can be configured for Java.

I have found the following part-solutions:

[JSF Code formatter or Eclipse XML Editor, each tag for new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22139262/jsf-code-formatter-or-eclipse-xml-editor-each-tag-for-new-line)

However, just placing attributes on the next line, indenting them by one is not enough:

```
<p:spinner
    id="multi-trade-adjust-count"
    value="#{bulkTradeManager.count}"
    title="Number of trades to create"
    maxlength="2"
    size="1"
    min="1"
    max="50"
    styleClass="bx-spinner mb-5px"
    style="width: 60px;">
    <p:ajax
        listener="#{bulkTradeManager.onCountChange}"
        process="@this"
        update=":content-form:data-panel" />
</p:spinner>
```

I am so unhappy with it, that I end up using no JSF formatters at all. What I'm desparately looking for is a result like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

    <p:dataTable id="multi-data-add"
                 value="#{bulkTradeManager.dataModel}"
                 var="trd"
                 rowIndexVar="rowIndex"
                 rowKey="#{trd.id}"
                 editable="true"
                 editMode="cell"
                 rowStyleClass="#{bulkTradeManager.lastNonRemovableIndex le rowIndex ? 'ui-state-highlight' : ''}"
                 styleClass="mb-10px mr-10px">

        <p:ajax event="cellEdit"
                listener="#{bulkTradeManager.onCellEdit}"
                update=":content-form:msgs" />

        <p:ajax event="sort" />

        <p:column headerText="#{msg['common.active.header']}"
                  rendered="#{bulkTradeManager.showingConstantColumns}"
                  styleClass="text-center">
            <h:outputText value="#{trd.active ? msg['common.yes.label'] : msg['common.no.label']}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="#{msg['entity.trade.transactionNbr.shortHeader']}"
                  rendered="#{bulkTradeManager.showingConstantColumns}">
            <h:outputText value="#{trd.transactionNbr}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="#{msg['entity.trade.referenceNbr.shortHeader']}"
                  sortBy="#{trd.referenceNbr}">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{trd.referenceNbr}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText id="reference-number-input"
                                 value="#{trd.referenceNbr}"
                                 styleClass="width-190px" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="#{msg['entity.trade.quantity.header']}/#{msg['common.nominal.header']}*"
                  sortBy="#{trd.quantity}">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{trd.quantity}">
                        <f:convertNumber maxIntegerDigits="126" pattern="#,###,##0.########" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText id="quantity-input"
                                 value="#{trd.quantity}"
                                 required="false"
                                 requiredMessage="#{msg['entity.trade.quantity.requiredMessage']}"
                                 maxlength="50"
                                 styleClass="width-190px">
                        <pe:keyFilter regEx="/[0-9,.]/i" />
                        <f:convertNumber maxIntegerDigits="126" pattern="#,###,##0.########" />
                    </p:inputText>
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        ...
```

This means, on top of the option "Split multiple attributes each on a new line", at least two sub options need to be present to produce this:

```
[✓] Split multiple attributes each on a new line
    [✓] Leave first attribute on the same line as the opening tag
    [✓] Align attributes column-wise
```

**Q**:

**Does anything like this exist?**

Maybe a JSF formatter plugin? Maybe there are some hacks via the config files?

---

Addendum:

As it stands now, JSF, XHTML, XML, HTML etc. formatting is a somewhat incomplete feature, at least the long-term solution would be to offer a configuration that is more like the Java code formatters where almost anything can be configured.

I'd even be tempted to contribute to the Eclipse community, if it's not overly hard to implement the two check boxes described. At least, leaving the first attribute on the same line and using the second character's column index after the opening tag and taking it for all subsequent attributes as indent seems doable to me...

Comment: Have you tried the jboss tools plugin?

Comment: How can the JBoss Tools format XHTML code?

Comment: By pressing Ctrl-shift-f

Comment: Of course, this is the shortcut that produces this weird indentation. But why is the JBoss Tools? I thought it's Eclipse WTP.