# How to indent any XML files with two spaces (instead of tab) in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor

I know how to indent any Java files by using the "Source", "Correct
indentation" Menu.
How to indent any XML files with two spaces (instead of tab)?
When I am editing a java file, in the java perspective, the Source menu appear, but when
I change to an XML file in the same perspective, the Source menu disappear so I
don't know how to indent it.
I use the latest Eclipse for Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

[Format XML code in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527474/format-xml-code-in-eclipse)

This link seems to help - eclipse lets you autoformat code using Ctrl+Shift+F and you should be able to customise what the autoformat will actually do in Window -> Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor.

Comment: I tried the answer in the link but it does not work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? What happens instead?

Comment: I tried the answer in the link but it does not work : I had done Window -> Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor.  I had opened the XML file by the Text and then XML Editor.  I had done CTRL+A to select the entire text and then CTRL+SHIFT+F but the file is unchanged - no identation had happened.   My Eclipse Version: Juno Service Release 2, Build id: 20130225-0426

Comment: Is the option actually there to change indentation and the like?

Comment: The Source menu disappear whenever a XML file is clicked.