# Where are the Eclipse XML Editor Preferences?

Tags: xml, eclipse, macos

I am following the directions for the accepted answer to an old question, [Format XML code in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527474/format-xml-code-in-eclipse), but I don't seem to have `Window -> Preferences` in Eclipse Luna under Mac OSX Mavericks. (I have the "Eclipse Modeling Tools" installed, in case that makes a difference.) `Eclipse -> Preferences` does not have any part of `XML -> Xml Files -> Editor`. What am I missing?

Comment: Which Luna download did you get? Does it actually contain the XML Editors and Tools? https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php?release=luna

Comment: @nitind: I have "Modeling Tools". Looks like that package doesn't have XML editors. Will I be able to install them? (When I searched the marketplace for `XML`, I got error messages.)

Comment: I found a way around the error messages and found a couple of XML editors. Do either of those come with Eclipse normally?

Comment: You should already have the Luna Update Site set within Eclipse. Just help->Install New Software and you should be able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac version of Eclipse 'Windows > Preferences' is moved to 'Eclipse > Preferences' (also 'Help > About' is moved to 'Eclipse > About Eclipse'). This is to be consistent with other Mac apps.

Not all downloads of Eclipse include the Web Tools which contains the XML editor. You can use 'Help > Install New Software' to install this.

Select the main Luna site (Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna) in 'Work with').

Choose 'Eclipse XML Editors and Tools' in the 'Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development' section.

Comment: I did that and am now getting the error, `Unhandled event loop exception`. I'm guessing I will need to download another fresh Eclipse installation that includes XML tools. :-(

Comment: I used exactly this method to install the XML tools on my Mac.